# Which crops grow in which seasons?

Tags: story-of-seasons-olive-town

I'm having trouble finding a comprehensive list of all crops that are plantable/harvestable within in each season. I know that some crops can grow in multiple seasons, but I'd like to know all of my options in a particular season.

Answer (score -1):

From [this GameSkinny article](https://www.gameskinny.com/0s5lj/story-of-seasons-pioneers-of-olive-town-best-crops-for-each-season):

Spring crops:

> | Crop | Sell Price | Grow Time | Regrow | Seasons |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Turnip | 192 G | 4 days | N/A | Spring |
> | Onion | 286 G | 6 days | N/A | Spring, Summer |
> | Strawberry | 125 G | 8 days | N/A | Spring |
> | Garlic | 315 G | 3 days | 4 days | Spring |

Summer crops

> | Crop | Sell Price | Grow Time | Regrow | Seasons |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Pumpkin | 270 G | 5 days | N/A | Summer |
> | Melon | 525 G | 7 days | N/A | Summer, Fall |
> | Pineapple | 630 G | 8 days | N/A | Summer |
> | Corn | 242 G | 8 days | 4 days | Summer |

Fall crops

> | Crop | Sell Price | Grow Time | Regrow | Seasons |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Carrot | 300 G | 5 days | N/A | Fall |
> | Sweet Potato | 384 G | 6 days | 3 days | Fall |
> | Melon | 525 G | 8 days | N/A | Summer, Fall |
> | Spinach | 240 G | 8 days | 4 days | Fall |

Winter crops:

> | Crop | Sell Price | Grow Time | Regrow | Seasons |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Broccoli | 120 G | 6 days | 3 days | Winter, Spring |
> | Cabbage | 448 G | 7 days | N/A | Winter, Spring |
> | Leek | 200 G | 4 days | N/A | Winter |
> | Daikon Radish | 234 G | 4 days | N/A | Winter, Spring |

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/304866)

Comment: @galacticninja Fixed by quoting the relevant tables from the article in-post